# attempting to change the default login processing URL of spring security issues error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am attempting to change the default login processing URL of spring security, after changing it, it keeps defaulting to error 404 page. everything seems fine but I keep keeps getting error attempting to login, here is my snippets

```
<form action="/signin/action" role="form" method="POST"  name="frmValidation" novalidate>
  <div>
.......
</form
```

below is the spring-security configuration but not enabling login after it is set in spring-security

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(2);
                http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/index")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/dash
                .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/action")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

when I attempt to login, it throws error 404, what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any controller to handle `/signin/action` path?

Comment: no I do not....

Comment: And after trying to login you get 404 not foumd?

Comment: yes I do please

Comment: Please read my answer again.